# User.Identity is not retrieved when JWT auth is enabled

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have first started with a cookie authentication and somehow after also enabling JWT it doesnt let me to retrieve the user by the  User.Identity, object
and I found this article which suggested that you can enable both
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET

this is my program cs on the Authentication config

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE"/*"Identity.Application"*/;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";
}) 
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/identity/account/login";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
})
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer",options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    
    options.Authority = "/Security/Token/Validate"; // TODO: Update URL
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience=builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
    };
    

    
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];


            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                (path.StartsWithSegments("/ConnectionsHub")))
            {

                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
})
.AddPolicyScheme("JWT_OR_COOKIE", "JWT_OR_COOKIE", options =>
{
    // runs on each request
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
       
        string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer "))
            return "Bearer";

        return "Cookies";
    };
});
...
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: What 's the error message you got ? This article which suggested that you can enable both is based for asp.net core mvc , have you try to use jwt in Blazor server successfully?

Comment: @Qing Guo it just simply doesnt recognize the cookie when i use the AddJwtBearer method,no error just it doesnt retrieve the Identity from the user

Comment: Inside `options.ForwardDefaultSelector` what is the value of `authorization` variable?

Comment: In `AddAuthentication` try `options.DefaultScheme = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";`

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos it is null